# XSLT / XPATH How to properly process (and maybe concat) nested node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nested

I have the following XML structure:

```
<PARENT> <TEXT> I realy love <LINK> stackoverflow </LINK> it's amazing </TEXT> </PARENT>
```

I'm trying to transform this in "I realy love stackoverflow it's amazing" with "stackoverflow" treated in one of my template as a link.
In my XSL is use the following `<xsl:template match="/ | *"/>`
 and `<xsl:template match="text() | @*"/>`
 to disable built-in templates for recursive processing and automatic print of all text.

I'm transforming my XML in HTML and I've tried different things:

- `PARENT/.` gives me "I realy love stackoverflow it's amazing" in one piece but then I can't process the LINK node correctly (I would have it twice or link at the end...).
- `PARENT/TEXT/text()` gives me "I realy love" in this case I could treat the link but I won't have the second part of my TEXT node.

I'm thinking about concat but I don't see how it could work, I would end with text first and link at the end.

Any hints on how to handle such case ? Maybe with a copy ? Maybe there is a way to access second part of my TEXT node ? Maybe there is a way to do all this at once ?

Thanks a lot for your time reading and helping.

To simplify my question I used an example on the XML structure the true one I'm trying to process is:

```
<Item>
          <Paragraphe>soit les 2 noms accolés, séparés par un simple espace, dans un ordre choisi par eux et dans la limite d'un seul <LienIntra LienID="R10114" type="Définition de glossaire">nom de famille</LienIntra> pour chacun s'ils portent eux-mêmes le nom de leurs 2 parents.</Paragraphe>
        </Item>
```

For context here is my full XSL file (pretty dirty and still very WIP - with link handling not implemented as I don't know how to do yet)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="no"/>
  <!-- Override built-in template -->
  <xsl:template match="text() | @*"/>
  <xsl:template mode="general-content" match="text() | @*"/>
  <xsl:template mode="general-content" match="/ | *"/>
  <xsl:template mode="tab-title" match="text() | @*"/>
  <xsl:template mode="tab-pane" match="text() | @*"/>
  <!-- -->
  <xsl:template match ="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <script src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="/js/tether.min.js">
        </script>
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="/js/fonctions.js">
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- START-REGION: FilDAriane -->
  <xsl:template match="FilDAriane">
    <div id="fildariane">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="FilDAriane/Niveau">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- END-REGION: FilDAriane -->
  <!-- START-REGION: Introduction -->
  <xsl:template match="Publication/Introduction/Texte/Paragraphe">
    <div id="introduction">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- END-REGION: Introduction -->
  <!-- START-REGION: Accordeon -->
  <!-- START-SUBREGION Accordeon et Card Header -->
  <xsl:template match="/Publication/Texte">
    <div id="accordion" role="tablist">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Publication/Texte/Chapitre">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading{generate-id()}">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{generate-id()}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{}">
            <xsl:value-of select="Titre/Paragraphe"/>
          </a>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse{generate-id()}" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading{generate-id()}" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="BlocCas">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates mode="general-content"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- END-SUBREGION Accordeon et Card Header-->
  <!-- START-SUBREGION Card Body Structure-->
  <xsl:template match="/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/BlocCas[@affichage='onglet']">
    <nav class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab{generate-id()}" role="tablist">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="tab-title"/>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tab{generate-id()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="tab-pane"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template mode="tab-title" match="/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/BlocCas[@affichage='onglet']/Cas">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position()=2">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-tab{generate-id()}" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav{generate-id()}" role="tab" aria-controls="nav{generate-id()}" aria-selected="true">
          <xsl:value-of select="Titre/Paragraphe"/>
        </a>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-tab{generate-id()}" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav{generate-id()}" role="tab" aria-controls="nav{generate-id()}" aria-selected="false">
          <xsl:value-of select="Titre/Paragraphe"/>
        </a>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template mode="tab-pane" match="/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/BlocCas[@affichage='onglet']/Cas">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position()=2">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav{generate-id()}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-tab{generate-id()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="general-content"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav{generate-id()}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-tab{generate-id()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="general-content"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- END-SUBREGION Card Body Structure-->
  <!-- START-SUBREGION Card Body Content -->
  <xsl:template mode="general-content" match="Liste[@type='puce']">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="Item">
        <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="general-content"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template mode="general-content" match="Paragraphe">
    <xsl:value-of select="./*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--  <xsl:template mode="general-content" match="LienIntra">
  <a href="TEST">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="general-content" match="LienInterne">
  <a href="TEST">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="general-content" match="/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/Paragraphe|/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/BlocCas/Cas/Paragraphe">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="general-content"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="general-content" match="/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/Liste[@type='puce']|/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/BlocCas/Cas/Liste[@type='puce']">
  <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="Item">
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="Paragraphe"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="general-content"/>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="general-content" match="/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/ANoter|/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/BlocCas/Cas/ANoter">
  <xsl:value-of select="Titre"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="Paragraphe"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="general-content"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="general-content" match="/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/Attention|/Publication/Texte/Chapitre/BlocCas/Cas/Attention">
  <xsl:value-of select="Paragraphe"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="general-content"/>
</xsl:template>-->
<!-- END-SUBREGION Card Body Content -->
<!-- END-REGION: Accordeon -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my full XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Publication xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ID="F10505" type="Fiche d'information" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../Schemas/3.0/Publication.xsd">
  <dc:title>Choix du nom de famille d'un enfant : nom de la mère, du père ou double-nom</dc:title>
  <dc:creator>Direction de l'information légale et administrative</dc:creator>
  <dc:subject>Papiers - Citoyenneté</dc:subject>
  <dc:description>Les parents peuvent choisir, sous certaines conditions, le nom que portera leur enfant. Une déclaration conjointe de choix de nom peut être faite avant ou après la déclaration de naissance. À défaut de choix, l’enfant porte le nom du parent dont la filiation est établie en premier ou celui du père en cas d’établissement simultané de la filiation.</dc:description>
  <dc:publisher>Direction de l'information légale et administrative</dc:publisher>
  <dc:contributor>Direction de l'information légale et administrative (Premier ministre), Ministère chargé de la justice</dc:contributor>
  <dc:date>modified 2017-03-21</dc:date>
  <dc:type>Fiche pratique</dc:type>
  <dc:format>text/xml</dc:format>
  <dc:identifier>F10505</dc:identifier>
  <dc:source>http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006424851&amp;idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006150015&amp;cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070721, http://circulaires.legifrance.gouv.fr/pdf/2011/11/cir_34124.pdf</dc:source>
  <dc:language>Fr</dc:language>
  <dc:relation>isPartOf N151</dc:relation>
  <dc:coverage>France entière</dc:coverage>
  <dc:rights>https://www.service-public.fr/a-propos/mentions-legales</dc:rights>
  <SurTitre>Fiche pratique</SurTitre>
  <Audience>Particuliers</Audience>
  <Canal>www.service-public.fr</Canal>
  <FilDAriane>
    <Niveau ID="Particuliers">Accueil particuliers</Niveau>
    <Niveau ID="N19810">Papiers - Citoyenneté</Niveau>
    <Niveau ID="N151">Nom et prénom</Niveau>
    <Niveau ID="F10505" type="Fiche d'information">Choix du nom de famille d'un enfant : nom de la mère, du père ou double-nom</Niveau>
  </FilDAriane>
  <Theme ID="N19810">
    <Titre>Papiers - Citoyenneté</Titre>
  </Theme>
  <SousThemePere ID="N103">État civil - Identité - Authentification</SousThemePere>
  <DossierPere ID="N151">
    <Titre>Nom et prénom</Titre>
    <SousDossier ID="N151-1">
      <Titre>Nom de famille</Titre>
      <Fiche ID="F10505">Choix du nom de l'enfant à sa naissance : mère, père ou double-nom</Fiche>
      <Fiche ID="F10506">Changement du nom de l'enfant après sa naissance</Fiche>
      <Fiche ID="F1656">Changement de nom pour motif légitime</Fiche>
    </SousDossier>
    <SousDossier ID="N151-2">
      <Titre>Prénom</Titre>
      <Fiche ID="F882">Choix du prénom de l'enfant</Fiche>
      <Fiche ID="F885">Changement de prénom</Fiche>
    </SousDossier>
    <SousDossier ID="N151-3">
      <Titre>Nom d'usage</Titre>
      <Fiche ID="F868">Utilisation du nom de son mari ou de sa femme</Fiche>
      <Fiche ID="F1343">Utilisation du nom des deux parents</Fiche>
    </SousDossier>
    <SousDossier ID="N151-4">
      <Titre>Adoption</Titre>
      <Fiche ID="F2668">Nom de famille et adoption plénière</Fiche>
      <Fiche ID="F2621">Nom de famille et adoption simple</Fiche>
    </SousDossier>
  </DossierPere>
  <SousDossierPere>Nom de famille</SousDossierPere>
  <Introduction>
    <Texte>
      <Paragraphe>Les parents peuvent choisir, sous certaines conditions, le nom que portera leur enfant.    Une déclaration conjointe de choix de nom peut être faite avant ou après la déclaration de naissance.    À défaut de choix, l’enfant porte le nom du parent dont la filiation est établie en premier ou celui du père en cas d’établissement simultané de la filiation.</Paragraphe>
    </Texte>
  </Introduction>
  <Texte>
    <Chapitre>
      <Titre>
        <Paragraphe>Quel nom peut-on donner à son enfant ?</Paragraphe>
      </Titre>
      <BlocCas affichage="onglet">
        <Cas>
          <Titre>
            <Paragraphe>Cas général</Paragraphe>
          </Titre>
          <Paragraphe>Un enfant dont la filiation est établie à l'égard de chacun des parents, peut porter : </Paragraphe>
          <Liste type="puce">
            <Item>
              <Paragraphe>soit le nom du père ;</Paragraphe>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Paragraphe>soit le nom de la mère ;</Paragraphe>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Paragraphe>soit les 2 noms accolés, séparés par un simple espace, dans un ordre choisi par eux et dans la limite d'un seul <LienIntra LienID="R10114" type="Définition de glossaire">nom de famille</LienIntra> pour chacun s'ils portent eux-mêmes le nom de leurs 2 parents.</Paragraphe>
            </Item>
          </Liste>
          <Paragraphe>Exemple : si le nom du père est Dupond Durand et la mère Dupuis, l'enfant pourra porter le nom de Dupond Dupuis.</Paragraphe>
          <ANoter>
            <Titre>À noter</Titre>
            <Paragraphe>un  nom composé existant avant 2005 constitue un nom unique, qui est indissociable et est donc transmis intégralement. Un nom composé suite à une <LienInterne LienPublication="F2621" type="Fiche d'information" audience="Particuliers">adoption simple</LienInterne>, quel que soit l'âge de l'adopté, est également indissociable et transmis intégralement.</Paragraphe>
          </ANoter>
        </Cas>
        <Cas>
          <Titre>
            <Paragraphe>L'un des parents est étranger</Paragraphe>
          </Titre>
          <Paragraphe>Un enfant dont la filiation est établie à l'égard de chacun des parents, peut porter : </Paragraphe>
          <Liste type="puce">
            <Item>
              <Paragraphe>soit le nom du père ;</Paragraphe>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Paragraphe>soit le nom de la mère ;</Paragraphe>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Paragraphe>soit les 2 noms accolés, séparés par un simple espace, dans un ordre choisi par eux et dans la limite d'un seul <LienIntra LienID="R10114" type="Définition de glossaire">nom de famille</LienIntra> pour chacun s'ils portent eux-mêmes le nom de leurs 2 parents</Paragraphe>
            </Item>
          </Liste>
          <Attention>
            <Titre>Attention</Titre>
            <Paragraphe>si le nom du ou des parents étrangers est constitué de plusieurs termes, il est considéré comme indivisible. Pour diviser le nom et n'en transmettre qu'une partie, vous devez produire un certificat de coutume.</Paragraphe>
          </Attention>
        </Cas>
      </BlocCas>
    </Chapitre>
    <Chapitre>
      <Titre>
        <Paragraphe>Comment choisir le nom de l'enfant ?</Paragraphe>
      </Titre>
      <Paragraphe>Le choix du nom de famille s'effectue par  le formulaire cerfa n°15286*01. Il s'agit d’un seul document signé à la même date par les père et mère, remis à l'officier de l'état civil avec la <LienInterne LienPublication="F961" type="Fiche d'information" audience="Particuliers">déclaration de naissance</LienInterne>. </Paragraphe>
      <ServiceEnLigne ID="R32739" URL="https://www.formulaires.modernisation.gouv.fr/gf/cerfa_15286.do" format="application/pdf" poids="197.1 KB" numerocerfa="15286*01" type="Formulaire">
        <Titre>Déclaration conjointe de choix de nom</Titre>
        <Source ID="R30663">Ministère chargé de la justice</Source>
        <Introduction>
          <Texte>
            <Paragraphe>Permet aux parents de déclarer le nom de famille choisi pour leur enfant.</Paragraphe>
          </Texte>
        </Introduction>
      </ServiceEnLigne>
      <Paragraphe>Si le couple a déjà un enfant né avant 2005, le choix de nom est possible pour le plus jeune, sous certaines conditions, seulement si l'aîné des enfants n'a pas fait l'objet d'une déclaration d'ajout de nom ou de déclaration conjointe de changement de nom.</Paragraphe>
      <Paragraphe>Si le couple a déjà un enfant né après le 1<Exposant>er</Exposant> janvier 2005, le choix de nom est possible pour le plus jeune :</Paragraphe>
      <Liste type="puce">
        <Item>
          <Paragraphe>si la filiation de l'aîné ne permettait pas une déclaration de choix de nom ;</Paragraphe>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Paragraphe>et qu'aucune déclaration de changement de nom n'a été faite ultérieurement.</Paragraphe>
        </Item>
      </Liste>
    </Chapitre>
    <Chapitre>
      <Titre>
        <Paragraphe>Quel nom en l'absence de choix des parents ?</Paragraphe>
      </Titre>
      <BlocCas affichage="radio">
        <Cas>
          <Titre>
            <Paragraphe>Les parents sont mariés ensemble</Paragraphe>
          </Titre>
          <Paragraphe>En l'absence de déclaration conjointe de choix de nom, l'enfant  prend    le nom du père.</Paragraphe>
          <Paragraphe>L'absence de choix équivaut à un choix et s'impose aux autres enfants.</Paragraphe>
        </Cas>
        <Cas>
          <Titre>
            <Paragraphe>Les parents ne sont pas mariés ensemble</Paragraphe>
          </Titre>
          <Paragraphe>En l'absence de déclaration conjointe de choix de nom, l'enfant prend le nom de celui de ses parents à l'égard duquel sa filiation est établie en premier.</Paragraphe>
          <Paragraphe>Par exemple, si le père reconnaît l'enfant après la déclaration de naissance, l'enfant prend le nom de sa mère.</Paragraphe>
          <Paragraphe>Si la filiation est établie simultanément entre les deux parents, l'enfant prend le nom du père.</Paragraphe>
          <Paragraphe>L'absence de choix équivaut à un choix et s'impose aux autres enfants.</Paragraphe>
          <ANoter>
            <Titre>À noter</Titre>
            <Paragraphe>en  cas de <LienInterne LienPublication="F10555" type="Fiche Question-réponse" audience="Particuliers">désaccord entre les parents</LienInterne>,  l'enfant prend  le nom des deux parents accolés selon l'ordre alphabétique.</Paragraphe>
          </ANoter>
        </Cas>
      </BlocCas>
    </Chapitre>
    <Chapitre>
      <Titre>
        <Paragraphe>Quels sont les effets du choix du nom ?</Paragraphe>
      </Titre>
      <Paragraphe>Le choix effectué pour l'aîné s'impose aux enfants plus jeunes du couple. Pour cela, leur filiation doit avoir été établie à l'égard des deux parents à la date de la déclaration de naissance.</Paragraphe>
      <Paragraphe>Le choix du nom est définitif.</Paragraphe>
    </Chapitre>
  </Texte>
  <VoirAussi important="non">
    <Fiche ID="F2668" audience="Particuliers">
      <Titre>Adoption plénière : conséquence sur le nom de famille</Titre>
      <Theme ID="N19810">
        <Titre>Papiers - Citoyenneté</Titre>
      </Theme>
    </Fiche>
    <Fiche ID="F2621" audience="Particuliers">
      <Titre>Adoption simple : conséquence sur le nom de famille</Titre>
      <Theme ID="N19810">
        <Titre>Papiers - Citoyenneté</Titre>
      </Theme>
    </Fiche>
  </VoirAussi>
  <OuSAdresser ID="R1" type="Local personnalisé sur SP">
    <Titre>Mairie</Titre>
    <Complement>Pour établir la déclaration de choix de nom</Complement>
    <PivotLocal>mairie</PivotLocal>
    <RessourceWeb URL="https://lannuaire.service-public.fr/"/>
    <Source ID="R30601">Service-public.fr</Source>
  </OuSAdresser>
  <Reference type="Texte de référence" URL="http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006424851&amp;idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006150015&amp;cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070721" ID="R12161">
    <Titre>Code civil : article 311-21 à 311-24</Titre>
    <Complement>Choix du nom de famille pour un enfant</Complement>
  </Reference>
  <Reference type="Texte de référence" URL="http://circulaires.legifrance.gouv.fr/pdf/2011/11/cir_34124.pdf" ID="R2316" format="application/pdf" poids="1.0 MB">
    <Titre>Circulaire du 28 octobre 2011 portant sur divers actes de l'état civil relatifs à la naissance et à la filiation</Titre>
  </Reference>
  <ServiceEnLigne ID="R32739" URL="https://www.formulaires.modernisation.gouv.fr/gf/cerfa_15286.do" format="application/pdf" poids="197.1 KB" numerocerfa="15286*01" type="Formulaire">
    <Titre>Déclaration conjointe de choix de nom</Titre>
    <Source ID="R30663">Ministère chargé de la justice</Source>
  </ServiceEnLigne>
  <Definition ID="R10114">
    <Titre>Nom de famille</Titre>
    <Texte>
      <Paragraphe>Nom qui figure sur l'acte de naissance (appelé aussi <Expression>nom de naissance</Expression> ou <Expression>nom patronymique</Expression>)</Paragraphe>
    </Texte>
  </Definition>
  <QuestionReponse ID="F10555" audience="Particuliers">Quel nom de famille pour un enfant en cas de désaccord entre les parents ?</QuestionReponse>
</Publication>
```

Comment: I am afraid `<xsl:template match="/ | *"/>` disables any processing so why do you think you need that?

Comment: Doesn't it only disable recursion on child nodes ? I use it only for a certain template mode in which I need to control what is beeing processed because if not I got interferences with other nodes that have already been processed.

Comment: You haven't shown any context nor any modes but an empty template matching `/` means that in that mode any document node is not processed any further. So with normal processing with a primary input document node being the one with that processing starts there will be no further processing.

Comment: I added my full code thanks for advice, still it's pretty dirty.

Not considering my code and the built-in template overide I'm doing (I will correct this) what do you think is the proper way to deal with this kind of nested node ?

Comment: The proper way to transform e.g. `<PARENT> <TEXT> I realy love <LINK> stackoverflow </LINK> it's amazing </TEXT> </PARENT>` is to write a template matching `PARENT` and transform it to the target HTML you want e.g. `<xsl:template match="PARENT"><html><body><xsl:apply-templates/></body></html></xsl:template>` and then `<xsl:template match="LINK"><a  href="?"><xsl:apply-templates/></a></xsl:template>`, making use of the recursive processing that makes XSLT so powerful, not by restricting it.

Comment: Okey indeed, I wrote a realy simple template following what you say and it's working fine. I gonna redo everything from scratch respecting the XSLT intended implementation.

It's hard to get used to this when youre a newbee sorry about disrespecting XSLT haha